# How to understand the currying in Swift?

Tags: swift, currying

I'm new to Swift, and when I look the book, I found the currying in Swift is complicated, and I write the code follow the book, such as:

```
func curry<A, B, C>(f: (A, B) -> C) -> A -> B -> C {
    return { x in { y in f(x, y) } }
}
func paraFunc(pa: Int, pb: Int) -> Int {
    return pa - pb
}
var cab = curry(paraFunc)
cab(2)(3)
```

and I don't know how to comprehend the "-> A -> B -> C". And I know the Generics. But I confused about the func curry, how it works? and anybody can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-> operator is right associative. So we can rewrite curry function like this.

```
func curry<A, B, C>(f: @escaping (A, B) -> C) -> ((A) -> ((B) -> C)) {
  return { x in { y in f(x, y) } }
}
```

Every `(` matches with `{` inside return part.

EDIT: Further explanation

`curry` function takes a non-curried two argument function and makes it curried. For example we have:

```
func sum(a: Int, b: Int) -> Int {
    return a + b
}
```

Now we can use this function like this:

```
let result = sum(3, 6)
```

But if we make it curried

```
let curriedSum = curry(sum)
```

Now we can use it like this:

```
let result = curriedSum(3)(6)
```

At first this seems unnecessary and complex. But think about what next expression does.

```
let sumWith3 = curriedSum(3)
```

This produces a new function that takes an `Int` sums it with 3. Now here we created a new function from another function. Now we can use it like any other function.

Currying is common paradigm in functional programming. In fact in Haskell (another functional programming language) every function is curried by default.

Comment: Did you mean call the curry(paraFunc) give me a func which I need pass in x return a (B -> C) func type, then I call the func cab(2) , it returns a func which we need pass in y? Then the func cab(2)(3) calculate the value exactly?

Comment: I never used the functional programming language before, so it's hard for me to understand the functional programming in Swift at first. And thanks for your further explanation, now I think I understand what the curry do. When I call the curriedSum(3) it return me a new function that it requires a parameter, next time I give a parameter to the 'sumWith6', it executes the parameter 'f: (A, B) -> C' and return the value to me, is it right? and thank you.